# Aligning text block with top of container

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve the *equivalent* of (I know it is not actually permitted in CSS) :

`{padding-top : -3x }`

In this original [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hotbelgo/3cpQz/) you can see that I want my h2 content to be aligned with the very top and bottom of the enclosing block element.

My -ve `margin-left` works, but a -ve margin-top moves the enclosing element upwards (taking the `h2` with it).  What I want is for the white letters to bleed into the background, so I need to be able to move the text to the top of the enclosing block element and reliably to set the vertical height of the `<header>` so that the bottom edge also bleeds into the background. So far it is very trial-and-error which I suspect will mean that it fails on other browsers, but I can't find any css options that do a better job.

Based on the first two first two answers, I have updated the **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hotbelgo/3cpQz/11/)**, but I'm still left with the `3em` font and `2.05em` line-height for the container (and having heard that you should **not** generally add units to line height as well, which would lead me toward a [line height of 0.7](http://jsfiddle.net/hotbelgo/3cpQz/10/)) and wondering whether that is a robust relationship (and if so how is it expressed mathematically) across all situations including mobile phones?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use a San-Serif font like Arial.. see [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qJArc/)

```
#experience {
    background-color: black;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0em 0;
    line-height: 2.05em;
}
#experience h2 {
    color: white;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    margin-left: -5px;
    font-family: "Arial";    
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 3em;
    letter-spacing: 0.1em;
}
```

Cheers Adam